# insert into with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, prepared-statement

I try to insert data from a form into a database and it doesn't work. 
I created a table named "vc" :

```
CREATE TABLE `vc` (
    `ID_VC` int(20) NOT NULL,
    `VC_ID_VC` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ID_USER` int(20) NOT NULL,
    `ID_VC_STATUS` int(2) NOT NULL,
    `ID_VC_VERSION` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `VALUECHAIN_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `VC_DESCRIPTION` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
    `VC_CREATION_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `VC_LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `vc`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_VC`),
    ADD KEY `FK_USER_VALUE_CHAIN_AUTHOR` (`ID_USER`),
    ADD KEY `FK_VC_PARENT_TRANS` (`VC_ID_VC`),
    ADD KEY `FK_VC_STATUS` (`ID_VC_STATUS`),
    ADD KEY `FK_VC_VERSION` (`ID_VC_VERSION`);
```

My form is using data from other tables and I display them into the form elements. My form looks like this :

```
<?php
    include 'include/dbconnect.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $userFields = 'SELECT ID_USER,USER_NAME,USER_SURNAME FROM user;';
    $vcstatusFields ='SELECT ID_VC_STATUS, VC_STATUS_NAME FROM vc_status;';
?>
<form method="post" action="create.php">
    <label>Nom</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text">        
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Auteur</label>
    <select name="author" id="author" class="form-control input-lg">
        <?php
            foreach ($pdo->query($userFields) as $row) {
                echo '<option  value="' .$row['ID_USER'] . '" id="' .$row['ID_USER'] . '"> ' . $row['USER_NAME'] . ' ' . $row['USER_SURNAME'] . '</option>';
             }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Statut</label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
        <?php
            foreach ($pdo->query($vcstatusFields) as $row) {
                echo '<option value="' .$row['ID_VC_STATUS'] . '" id="' .$row['ID_VC_STATUS'] . '">' . $row['VC_STATUS_NAME'] . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

Finally, I have to create an insertion into the database but it doesn't seem to work and no error message appears.

```
<?php
include 'include/dbconnect.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

// Attempt insert query execution
try{
    // create prepared statement
    $vcSQL = "INSERT INTO vc (VALUECHAIN_NAME, VC_DESCRIPTION, ID_USER, ID_VC_STATUS) VALUES (:name,:description,:author,:status)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($vcSQL);

    // bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_REQUEST['VALUECHAIN_NAME']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $_REQUEST['VC_DESCRIPTION']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $_REQUEST['ID_USER']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $_REQUEST['ID_VC_STATUS']);

    // execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

Ideally, I would like to make the forming treatment in the same file where I put the form ... actually (as I begin PHP for less than a week). All help would be welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you get any error, or what exactly your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insert use the names in the form instead of $_REQUEST['column_names'].

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_REQUEST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $_REQUEST['description']);
$stmt->bindParam(':author', $_REQUEST['author']);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_REQUEST['status']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because on the INSERT, you don't set all of the fields that are required, for example 'ID_VC' must be NOT NULL (as declare on the CREATE TABLE statement), but you don't set a value for this field.

You may get the the error information with `$pdo->errorInfo()` for more information.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i had to change my $_request :
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_REQUEST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $_REQUEST['description']);
$stmt->bindParam(':author', $_REQUEST['author']);

the ID_VC field is an autoincrement ... so i don't have to put a value inside it if i'm right..
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_REQUEST['status']);

Comment: Oh, yeah, if there's AUTO INCREMENT, there's no issue (it just wasn't on the create statement, that's why I thought this was the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Change $_REQUEST With $_POST['name']

Where Name Same Name In html Form

and
$pdo->query($vcstatusFields)

Not Return An Array But Return Pdo Object So You Must Fetch The Result 
Something like this

$array = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
Then Loop Through it As You Do For More Fetch style 
[Fetch Style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)